# Effect of having infrared reflective paint on a room with and without a heat source

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, infrared-radiation, thermal-conduction

I am trying to check if my understanding is correct. This is not really a question but a request for validation. I hope this is allowed.

When painting with a heat reflective paint there are two options

A- The room does not contain a significant heat source. This will always lead to a reduction in ambient temperature as heat from the outside is not allowed in. Heat by convection and conduction will still penetrate but overall the energy transfer will decrease.

B- The room contains a heat source emitting IR rays. The rays will keep bouncing over the painted walls until it is absorbed by the air or the body of the heat source itself.

Depending on the ratio between the external and internal IR sources, a IR reflective paint can lead to either increase or decrease of ambient temperature

Comment: I thought that infrared reflecting paint is used on roofs and outside buildings to reduce the effect of sunlight heating them in hot countries.IMO any effect in painting walls inside the house will be  tiny. https://www.scielo.br/j/po/a/dkmgYstmPR4rXwcTmxpLKrw/

Comment: @annav It is used for that actually. What I am wondering about is what would happen if the house had heat generation somehow. Painting the inside should not be different from painting the outside

Comment: but it is the sun rays that heat the roofs and outside walls with  more than 1000 watts per meter square . I suppose that  reflection would keep the room a bit warmer, but the paint should have no effect different from usual paints as far as outside walls.